# Java-Selenium2: Need method explanation

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am a new to selenium2 and Java as well. Can somebody please explain what is happening in this code block especially from the line "String"? Please help

```
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
@After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
   String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's designed to fail the test suite if the `verificationErrors` `StringBuffer` has been populated by any preceding test. It also quits the current WebDriver instance beforehand.

It's incomplete because we can't see any of the `@Test` instances where `verificationErrors` might be getting appended-to. Also, appending one big string isn't a very good way of separating multiple errors.

You could rewrite more cleanly as:

```
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
  driver.quit();

  if (verificationErrors.length() > 0) {
      fail( verificationErrors.toString() );
  }
```

Comment: Andrew can you please explain what exactly this line                                        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) is performing.

Comment: Having converted the StringBuffer to a String, that line says: "if blank doesn't equal the string", i.e. is the string non-empty? Or: were there any errors? But you can do an equivalent check on the original StringBuffer: `if (verificationErrors.length() > 0)`, which should be simpler and easier to read.

Comment: Presumably you have `@Test` methods that append error messages to `verificationErrors` under some conditions?

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification.@Test code was just performing some registration and this string wasn't used there.

Comment: @Test
  public void testRegistration() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/HotelAppBuild2/index.php");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("New User Register Here")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("praveena86");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("testing");
    driver.findElement(By.id("re_password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("re_password")).sendKeys("testing");
    driver.findElement(By.id("email_add")).clear();
  }

Comment: No problem - please 'accept' the answer if you think it was a good explanation.